# Motherboard not powering up again

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have a B450 Steel Legend with a Ryzen 5 1600. I suspended the OS and never woke up again.

I turned off the PSU main switch and wait about an hour or two; turned on again but when I hit the power button doesn't do anything.
I also cleared the UEFI BIOS and even unplugged the motherboard main connector and short circuit the green and black wires and the PSU works okay.

The motherboard only have on board RGB on, always and none of the error LEDs are on or get any beep sound.

Answer (score 1):

This happened recently and I cannot say for sure why but the PSU needed to be replaced even if it was working but it seemed that it was right on the edge of providing enough power. If it will not power even if the disks are not connected, then it cannot be the operating system, just a coincidence which threw us off on a wrong track!

To validate, unplug everything inside the case until you have just the motherboard and PSU. Power on and see what happens. If it powers on, add a screen and GPU if there is no builtin graphics, check again. Repeat until it no longer powers on to find the culprit.

If it does not power on at all even just the PSU and MB, it's could be either. You'll have to replace one so try to borrow a PSU to see it is can run the MB but it's possible the motherboard just died.

Comment: Ok, now is running, I'm writing from it. Now I have attached a VGA, 1 LCD, mouse, keyboard, Ethernet and all is running ok. I will try to add more device after run a backup.